# The Space of Modular Forms and Riemann - Roch Theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-surfaces, modular-forms, geodesic, modular-group

Let $\Gamma$ be a normal subgroup of finite index of the modular group $PSL(2,\mathbb{Z})$.

I think that it is well-known that a function $f:\mathbb{H}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is called an entire modular form for the subgroup $\Gamma$ of dimension $-2$ if:

1. $f(g(z)) = (cz+d)^2 f(z)$, for all $z \in \mathbb{H}, g\in \Gamma$.
2. $f$ is holomorphic in $\mathbb{H}$.
3. $f$ is holomorphic at the cusps of $\Gamma$.

Let $C$ be the set of all cusps of $\Gamma$.

From the Riemann-Roch theorem, it is known that the dimension of the space of entire modular forms is $|C|-1+g$ (where $g$ is the genus of the compact Riemann surface $R= (\mathbb{H}\cup C)/\Gamma$).

It is then mentioned that The $\mathbb{R}-$dimension of the space $M_{\mathbb{R}}$ of entire forms taking real values at the cusps is $2g+|C|–1$.

How could this be done?

I mean how the space $M_{\mathbb{R}}$ of entire forms taking real values at the cusps, that is a subspace of the space of entire modular forms of dimension $-2$, has dimension bigger than the original space?

**Asymptotic Winding of the Geodesic Flow on Modular Surfaces and Continuous Fractions**. *Y. Guivarc'h* and *Y. Le Jan*. Page **26**.
[image]

Comment: Can you construct a few Eisenstein series in this space? (called $M_k(\Gamma)$ the weight 2 modular forms for $\Gamma$)

Comment: Called $M_2(\Gamma)$

Comment: @reuns If I had known, I wouldn't have asked.

Comment: What do you think of $\sum_{\gamma\in \Gamma} \gamma'(z)-\sum_{\gamma\in \Gamma} (\alpha\gamma)'(z)$

Comment: @reuns To be honest, I have no idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy answer to your question as stated, not telling much because the important clues/theorems are left hidden in your statement, is that $g$ is the (complex vector space) dimension of the holomorphic 1-forms on $(\mathbb{H}\cup C)/\Gamma$, which is the same as
$S_2(\Gamma)$, which is the kernel of the map $$f\mapsto (\Gamma c(i\infty)\in C\mapsto f|_2 \Gamma c(i\infty))$$
sending $f$ to its values at the cusps.

$\sum_{c\in C} f|_2 c(i\infty)=0 $ because otherwise  $\sum_{\gamma\in \Gamma\backslash SL_2(\Bbb{Z})} f|_2 \gamma$ would be non-zero in $M_2(SL_2(\Bbb{Z}))$.

Whence for any set of values at the cusps summing to zero there is some $f\in M_2(\Gamma)$ taking those values (since otherwise $\dim_\Bbb{C}M_2(\Gamma)$ would be less than $g+|C|-1$).

And hence with $M_2(\Gamma)_\Bbb{R}$ the real vector subspace of $M_2(\Gamma)$ taking real values at the cusps we get that $M_2(\Gamma)_\Bbb{R}/ S_2(\Gamma) \cong \Bbb{R}^{|C|-1}$ ie. $\dim_\Bbb{R}(M_2(\Gamma)_\Bbb{R})=2g + |C|-1$

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. However, I am still facing some difficulties. First of all, why do we have that $\sum_{c\in C} f|_2 c(i\infty)=0 $?. Secondly, as you have mentioned that "Whence for any set of values at the cusps summing to zero there is some $f\in M_2(\Gamma)$ taking those values", I did not get the reason. Finally, why do we have that $M_2(\Gamma)_\Bbb{R}/ S_2(\Gamma) \cong \Bbb{R}^{|C|-1}$?.